# Give arguments to executed script

Tags: bash, arguments

I have a first script getting arguments like this :

```
while getopts "m:t:r:zsqhc:" opt 2>/dev/null
do
    case ${opt} in
    m) machine=${OPTARG,^^}
    ;;
    t) [...];;
    .
    .
```

And so on. As you can see, some arguments need a value (like a string or a number), and some other don't.

This script then calls two other scripts, which need the same arguments.
I would like to know how to give those scripts the arguments.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Shift](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html) you can account for arguments with and without values

Save your arguments (or a subset) in a variable to pass them to your other scripts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did it this way :
    `tmp=""
    while (( "$#" )); do
    tmp="$tmp $1"
    shift
    done

    echo $tmp`
It returned me a string with all the arguments in the order I gave to my test script.
I'm sorry the comment doesn't want to get the return char.